# Getting the client IP when passing through a reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, ip-forwarding

In my VPS I am hosting several websites. everyone living in its own Linux Container. For instance

> Site #1 -> 10.0.3.111
>
> Site #2 -> 10.0.3.112
>
> Site #3 -> 10.0.3.113

To know where to redirect each request, I also have a reverse proxy nginx in another Linux Container in `10.0.3.101`

The problem I am having is that in one of my websites, which is running Laravel, I try to get the IP of the client, like this:

```
<p>IP Address: {{ Request::getClientIp() }}</p>
```

The problem is that I am getting all the time `10.0.3.101`, instead of the IP of the client.

I guess Laravel is getting the IP of the last host where the request came thought, not the initial one that started the request.

Is there a way that I could get that IP, without changing this structure?

**Configurations**

This is my nginx hostfile:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_pass http://10.0.3.115;
        }
}
```

Comment: Laravel should look at `X-Real-IP` or `X-Forwarded-For` headers.

Comment: Yeah, but as you see, I already forward those values, and I still get the IP of the machine hosting the reverse proxy...

Comment: I don't know Laravel, but googling suggest, you need to use [setTrustedProxies](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_setTrustedProxies) before

Comment: This line is interesting: `Request::setTrustedProxies(array( '10.0.3.101' ));` but where should I put it?

Comment: Indeed, that was it! I added it to the `start.php` and it worked. Alexey, if you put it into an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [trusted proxy](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/trusting_proxies.html). In that case `getClientIp()` will use `X-Forwarder-For` header to get client IP address.